# Angular 1.x re-render

Tags: angularjs

I was rendering a large table, with multiple groups, nested ng-repeats, etc.., with thousands of model. Obviously performance to render the table was very slow, on the order of 4-5 seconds.

I could have sped it up by using the bind once functionality (::model), but then I would never have been able to update the table. What I really needed was a way to update the markup for the entire table, rather than update individual cells (so I really do not need the individual watches for every cell in the table).

I ended up rendering the table using JavaScript,$interpolate and $sce, which now takes less than 50ms, and the only model being watched is the html markup for the table. When a condition changes, the whole markup is regenerated and the view updated. However, this seems to defeat the purpose of Angular, having to code a view manually in JS rather than using a template.

What I really needed was a way to use bind once (::model), to have no watches on the individual table data, along with a way to re-render a whole DOM structure, by watching a model, such as a counter that would be incremented every time a condition changed.

Something like this:

```
<div id="detailTable" ng-rerender="someModel">         
     <div ng-repeat... using bind once
     <div ng-repeat... using bind once
     <div ng-repeat... using bind once
     <div ng-repeat... using bind once
           <div ng-repeat... using bind once
     ...
</div>
```

However I could not find anything like this, even though it seems obvious it should exist, did I miss something?

Comment: This repaint rate challenge may be useful for you http://mathieuancelin.github.io/js-repaint-perfs/ there are 5 implementations of Angular 1.x with different optimization techniques, code is here https://github.com/mathieuancelin/js-repaint-perfs

Comment: Just FYI rendering huge tables has a rendering impact for the browser, its far more efficient to render such things as a list of DIVs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be honest, I think the option of rendering the table without the full use of all the advantages that Angular has is not bad. Depending on the context, its advantages are our perdition.

Recently, in a project in which I am working, we faced a really important problem with the performance in the tables and its origin was what I named "the overuse of Angular". My case was the same than yours. Lots of watchers and scopes because lots of ng-repeat (per row, per cell, inside of the cells to render multi-data,...) and other Angular stuff (ng-class, ng-if,...). We spent hours in brainstorm meetings trying to find the best option. Of course we though in one data binding and so on, but the problem didn´t disappeared. Finally, we though "if the problem is coming from Angular, maybe we are overusing Angular"... We refactored our code and now, the performance is not a problem. Our tables are generated with a combination of Angular and DOM scripting. The deepest ng-repeat is to generate the rows, and each content of the row is generated with pure javascript by DOM scripting. We have found the equilibrium between the advantages of Angular and the advantages of DOM scripting, and it works. And our tables are sortables, filterables,...

Other case I know is the one that one colleague of mine was having. The situation was really similar and he decided to reduce the overuse of Angular and by combining its use with ReactJS.

So my conclusion is "don´t stop using Angular, but don´t close the doors to combine it with other alternatives". Having the ingredients is not enough to cook... we also need to know the recipe.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Interesting - but perhaps worth mentioning that DOM manipulation in Angular code is still bad practice and generally terrible idea. Except for: *within *directives**. Which are suitable exactly for such situations, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem that we dealt with namely by using Virtual Repeat technology.

If you are using AngularJS then the [Angular Material library](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) offers this out the box and if you are using Angular then [another library](https://github.com/rintoj/angular2-virtual-scroll) offers this functionality.

Note that Virtual Repeats do not work with tables, only with a list of DIVs. But a bonus is that browsers can render a list of DIVs perceptibly quicker than a table.

We created some simple CSS that makes DIVs appear and act like a table.  The result is the ability to render 1000s of rows extremely fast.

If it helps, here is the code I use in my "table" component to render the list itself.

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container flex class="table-body" scroll-shadow>
    <md-list-item class="table-row" layout="row" md-virtual-repeat="row in $ctrl.displayRows">
        <div class="table-cell {{$ctrl.headers[$index].className}}" ng-repeat="cell in row.cells">
            <div ng-if="cell.templateUrl" ng-include="cell.templateUrl"></div>
            <div ng-if="!cell.templateUrl" ng-bind-html="cell.contents"></div>
        </div>
    </md-list-item>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```